# Quiz android app using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've created an Activity that contains a ViewPager with `n` number of Fragments. I have also added a Previous, Next and Finish buttons. Fragments are either multiple choice ListViews or just a single answer type.

How should I get the data from each fragment when the user hits Finish? Should I get each answer on the onPageSelected event from the ViewPager?

Comment: Are you asking when or how?

Comment: Asked How and suggested When.

Answer (score 1):

Communications between a Fragment and the activity that contains it is done via Interfaces.

The fragment should expose an interface listener and the activity should implement it and get notified by the fragment once an event happens.

You can use my example, and you can also change so the activity doesn't implement, but you can create the listener in run time anonymously (like you do for buttons on click listener many times).

```
class MyFragment {

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnNextPageListener {
        public void onNextPageSelected(String DataString);
    }

    // define listener in fragment
    OnNextPageListener mNextPageListener;

.... class code

  @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      try {
            mNextPageListener = (OnNextPageListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnNextPageListener");
        }
.... class code...

   ...button press onclick listener method...
   mNextPageListener.onNextPageSelected("My Name is Slim Shaddy");

}


class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.OnNextPageListener 
    public void onNextPageSelected(String StringData) {
    }
    ...
```

read more here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Either way I suggest you do this when someone pressed the button in the fragment, or hooking the ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, starting the saving the data on onPageScrollStateChanged and completing it on the OnPageSelected so you ensure you have the data even if the fragment is not available anymore.

Comment: I've placed the buttons on the Activity but I think I understand the pattern you're suggesting.

Comment: it's fine, you can have them on the activity too, no problem. read the link I posted, you can also communicate back with the fragment too, so you can ask it for it's data.